# alphanumeric auto increment id using angularjs php and mysql

Tags: php, mysql, angularjs, auto-increment, unique-id

[image: click here for UI][interface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W2Trt.png)

I have an interface implemented using angularjs, php and database is  mysql and there I have a field call hop reference Ex:- 7G/0001 the 1st part is the frequency and a slash  and the frequency should be the selected one from the combo box and the other part should be auto increment in the database for an example the next one could be 8G/0002. How do I implement this using angularjs, php and mysql.

Thanks

Comment: Can you give a little bit more information on what you are trying to do?

Comment: there's a link above to click to appear the user interface image that i have uploaded .. i have a combo box where the user can select the frequency either 7G,8G or 13G likewise .and also im having a field call hop reference (it's unique and behave like the primary key of the table)  the 1st part of that should be the selected frequency with a slash and the next part should be the auto increment part in the database.. for example the the 1st record in the table would be 7G/0001 the next one would be 13G/0002 .. do i need to write a php script or trigger in mysql ..

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9HE9l.png   here is the user interface .

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to store two different fields: frequency and id. Then in your queries, concatenate the values together. By using the auto increment field, you avoid any possibility of duplicate values or concurrency issues.

Example

```
CREATE TABLE ees.foo (
   frequency VARCHAR(2) NOT NULL,
   id INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL
);
```

Sql query

```
SELECT concat(frequency,'/',lpad(id, 4, '0')
  FROM tbl
```